# How can i kill thread when it in while loop C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, while-loop

I have a while loop that checking true/false. And also I have if block. The if block Counting down from 300 to 0. I want to kill the thread when it's 0 and two another place.

```
  Thread thread = new Thread(() =>{
    try {
      int countdown = 300;
      while (true) {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        paymentService.CheckPayment(pdId);
        if (result.Complete == false) {
          countdown--;
          if (countdown == 1) {
            //kill thread
          }
        }
        if (result.Complete == true) {
          //kill thread
          NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Pages/success.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception) {
      //kill thread
      Application.Current.Shutdown();
    }
  });
  thread.Start();

}
```

Comment: There is a class [CancellationToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997289(v=vs.110).aspx) that threads use for this.

Comment: Instead of a while loop with a Sleep(1000), you should likely should be using a timer instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
return;
```

will do - you just have to exit the method that the Thread runs;

Comment: If i use return; how can i break; ? I'm confused.

Comment: The return is the break. Split the thread code to a seperate method and call that function from your thread initialization and it will make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You may care to use a Tasks as opposed to Threads.  This is a possible solution:

```
void Main()
{
    Test(); 
}

void Test()
{
    var t = new Task(() => {
        var rnd = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
        int countdown = 5;
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(10);
            var nextRand = rnd.Next(5);
            Console.WriteLine(nextRand);
            if (nextRand == 0)
            {
                countdown--;
                if (countdown == 1) return;
            }
        }
    });
    var t2 = t.ContinueWith(_ => { });

    t.Start();
    t2.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("Thread ended");
}
```